# Why are Laravel flash messages blocked on livesite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Laravel flash message work on my staging server, but not on live.  I have same code and server php versions.  Could it be a security measure to block passing the values in some way, as these are redirects?

Controller code looks like,

```
     // Need to flash message
     return redirect()->route('login')->with('alert-success', 'Successfully 
     activated your account, please login.');
```

View code like,

```
      @include('guardians.shared.messages.error')
      @include('guardians.shared.messages.success')
```

Comment: Could be lots of things. Is your dev server configured exactly like your production server? Are there any error logs that have clues?

Comment: no errors but that's expected as it's redirecting with no error but the message is missing.  The same config, but not production settings in app.php

Comment: How are you outputting the flash message in blade?

Comment: Are you using the same session driver on both staging and production? Also, are other session data being persisted as expected? Such as authentication for example.